# Dynamic variable names in Ruby (on the Rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I need to store character stats to a `MySQL` database using the `Ruby on the Rails` framework. It seems that I can't use arrays in my database without transitioning to `PostgreSQL`, which I am not able to do at present. So, I thought that dynamic variable names would be the key but I'm not sure how to create them. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
class CreateInventories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :inventories do |t|
      t.string :user_name
      t.string :char_name
      t.string :char_item1
      t.string :char_item2
      t.string :char_item3
      t.string :char_item4
      t.string :char_item5
      t.string :char_item6
      t.string :char_item7
      t.string :char_item8
      t.string :char_item9
      t.string :char_item10
      t.string :char_item11
      t.string :char_item12
      t.string :char_item13
      t.string :char_item14
      t.string :char_item15
      t.string :char_item16
      t.string :char_item17
      t.string :char_item18
      t.string :char_item19
      t.string :char_item20


      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Obviously this is horrible. Can anyone tell me a way of sorting it out so that it doesn't use 20 lines of code to create what really should only be one variable?

Comment: Those aren't dynamic variable names, they're field names. It's easy to generate an iterator, dynamically create the strings, then turn them into symbols. I'd suggest researching how to do that.

Comment: "basic people"? Really? Insulting people who are helping you is not a good precedence, especially when you are new to the site. Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users, and then review the answer I've provided you.

Comment: In Ruby on the Rails they are both variable names and field names. char_item1 is a variable, a field, a string and a symbol, depending on what part of the process you investigate it at. The variable name is converted into a field at the point it hits the db, which is hasn't yet. But I think I understand your point, which is that because it's supposedly a 'field' it can't take arrays in the same way it would if it were not a 'field'. Well, not in MySQL anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested, but is the basis for generating strings or symbols dynamically:

```
create_table :inventories do |t|
  t.string :user_name
  t.string :char_name

  20.times do |i|
    t.string "char_item#{ 1 + i }".to_sym
  end

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `to_sym` isn't necessary, it is probably doing a `to_s` internally anyway.

Comment: I added `to_sym` just to make it apparent what the code is generating. I agree that Rails is probably doing `to_s` internally.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm sure your code is right but I'm getting ```undefined method `char_item1' for #<Inventory:0x9443d18>``` when attempting to access, though I was considering the code insertion method myself. Is the code-block actually appending to the variable name or is it doing something else?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend normalizing your data model. Although your structure would work for the first 20 items in an inventory, if you want to add another inventory slot you don't want to be doing a database migration.

If you stored the item data in a separate table, you could have an InventoryItems table that functions as a join table.

```
class CreateInventories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :inventory_items do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.string :inventory_slot
      t.references :item
    end
  end
end
```

This way, you can make your characters' inventory arbitrarily large without having to do any database migrations.

Comment: I do. Where did you get that idea from? There is a totally separate Users database.

Comment: Sorry, above comment references an incorrect original post.

Comment: So t.references is key? I'm not familiar with the ```references``` method/property -- are you familiar to the degree you could explain it, or find me links to a good explanation?